# Reliable C context window

Tags: c, vim, scope

I've recently started using the [`ctx`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=208) Vim addon.  This addon provides a "context" window that displays the layers of scope — function definitions, for loops, if statements, etc. — down to the current line.  It's really great! ..in theory.  In practice, I'm finding that it's not all that reliable.  I may just have bad luck; I've really only tried to use it on one file so far.

For example, within the [ExpandFromContext](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/ex_getln.c#4439) function in vim's `src/ex_getln.c`, the function signature is not displayed, just the opening brace.

This addon is pretty old (last update 2002) and the [author](http://n01se.net/chouser/) seems to have moved on to decidedly non-C things (looks like mostly clojure development).  So as such, there doesn't seem to be much point in filing a bug report.

Is there a fork of this addon or another one which provides more reliable parsing?

Answer (score 1):

Although basic this function has been very helpful to me. Got it from a friend who got it from a website so not claiming any authorship. Add it to your vimrc for getting the current function you're in. I've only used it in C/C++:

```
fun! ShowFuncName()
    let lnum = line(".")
    let col = col(".")
    echohl ModeMsg
    echo getline(search("^[^ \t#/]\\{2}.*[^:]\s*$", 'bW'))
    echohl None
    call search("\\%" . lnum . "l" . "\\%" . col . "c")
endfun

noremap <silent> <F3> :call ShowFuncName() <CR>
```

Comment: Well, it's only partway there, in that it only displays the function definitions and not other blocks, but it may be useful anyway.  I'm not sure how reliable it will be, but it does work on the function in question.  Note that you can pass the `'n'` flag to `search()` to avoid having to move the cursor back.

Answer (score 0):

May be the plug-in is also obsolete because there are some good other Vim features in the meanwhile, at least
- folding, 6 methods (:help folding),
- working with text objects (:help text-objects).

Comment: I'm familiar with both of these, but doing either `[zk[zk ...` repeatedly and then `^o^o...` or `zczc...zczz` and then `zozo...` is kind of a hassle, especially when jumping (via `^]`, the quickfix/location list, etc.) into the middle of deeply nested code.  More than being a hassle, it's a distraction and interrupts the flow of my concentration.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [SrcExpl](https://github.com/wesleyche/SrcExpl) is suitable for you.